# Create count limit query in spring boot java to fetch no of elements

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to fetch 5000 elements from 79K elements from mongodb can any one please tell how to write query for count limit in repository.

Comment: just want to create query only in repository for count if you know how to create query for limit count in repository then please let me know my requirement is only to write query for count just like this : @Query() inside this i want to write count limit

Comment: Use pageable ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are your two options:

```
  db.collection.find({}).limit(5000)

  db.collection.aggregate([ {},{},{$limit:5000}])
```

Comment: just want to create query only in repository for count if you know how to create query for limit count in repository then please let me know